# What are good load testing tools for IIS 7 web applications?

Tags: iis-7

The title says it all.  I'm looking for a good set of tools that I can use to load test a web application on IIS 7 before deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of good tools available:

Not free, but excellent if you are doing this professionally is Visual Studio Team System Test Load Agent.  MSDN covers how to set it up and run it here: [Controllers, Agents, and Rigs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182634.aspx).  You can download a trial here:

- [Visual Studio Team System 2010 Test Load Agent Beta 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1967F42A-1E8B-4C70-9329-8478B68097D9&displaylang=en)
- [Visual Studio Team System 2008 Test Load Agent (90-day Trial)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=572E1E71-AE6B-4F92-960D-544CABE62162&displaylang=en)

As far as free tools...

**[Web Capacity Analysis Tool (WCAT)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.04.utilityspotlight.aspx?pr=blog):**

**Overview:** Web Capacity Analysis Tool (WCAT) is a lightweight HTTP load generation tool primarily designed to measure the performance of a web server within a controlled environment.  WCAT can simulate thousands of concurrent users making requests to a single web site or multiple web sites.  The WCAT engine uses a simple script to define the set of HTTP requests to be played back to the web server. Extensibility is provided through plug-in DLLs and a standard, simple API.

**Features:**

- HTTP 1.0 and HTTP 1.1 capable
- Supports IPv6 Multithreaded Support
- Supports generating stress from multiple machines
- Extensible through C plug-in
- DLLs Supports Performance Counter integration
- Measures throughput and response time
- Supports SSL requests
- NTLM Authentication request support
- Easily supports testing thousand of concurrent users

Download the [x86 version here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2007/05/wcat-63-(x86)), and the [x64 version here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2007/05/wcat-63-(x64)).

Answer (score 4):

I believe Apache Bench is pretty widely used for this sort of thing and can be used without any problem against other webservers. It's command-line based, so it should be pretty easy to script into your test suite or pre-deployment scripts.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

Comment: ab is a good indicator but not much more. For real load testing you can't beat the 'web avalanche' appliance - you can rent them.

Comment: AB was just what I needed, I was having SSL problems using WCAT, and couldn't get most other tools to work. Didn't care much about the load, just wanted it to generate a bunch of requests so I could test my server.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Web Application Stress Tool before.  I'm wondering if this is a pretty standard tool to use, and if there are better alternatives

(WAS) can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e2c0585a-062a-439e-a67d-75a89aa36495&displaylang=en)

There's also a kb article on how to install and use the application [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313559)

and a blog on how to use it [here](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/webstress/webstress.htm)